# why do i get gibberish when i click on my image?

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf

I'm trying to upload a image using forms and then i need to keep it in the DB and see it later in a table.
The image displays correctly  when i run the localhost, the problem is when i click on the image and it show me gibberish instead of the image in format JPEG. i'm using thymeleaf and springboot.

this is the part of the code in the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorate="~{master.html}">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Administrar películas | Trailers </title>
</head>
<body>
<div layout:fragment="content">
    <h2> Peliculas</h2>

    <div class="text-end">
        <a href="/admin/peliculas/nuevo" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3">
            Nueva Película
        </a>
    </div>

    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Pelicula</th>
            <th>Fecha de estreno</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr th:each="pelicula : ${peliculas}" th:object="${pelicula}">
        <td style="width: 150px;">
            <a th:href="@{/assets/{filename}(filename=*{rutaPortada})}" class="img-thumbnail w-100" data-fancybox>
                <img th:src="@{/assets/{filename}(filename=*{rutaPortada})}" alt="" class="img-thumbnail w-100" >
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div th:text="*{titulo}" class="fs-5 fw-bold"></div>
                <p th:text="*{sinopsis}"></p>
                <div>
                    <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-light text-dark me-1"
                          th:each="genero : *{generos}"
                             th:text="${genero.titulo}"></span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td th:text="*{#temporals.format(fechaEstreno, 'dd/MM/yyyy')}"></td>
            <td class="text-end">
                <a th:href="@{/admin/peliculas/{id}/editar(id=*{id})}">Editar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>

and this it the part of the code from the controller



package com.cinetrailer.trailer.controller;

import com.cinetrailer.trailer.model.Genero;
import com.cinetrailer.trailer.model.Pelicula;
import com.cinetrailer.trailer.repo.GeneroRepository;
import com.cinetrailer.trailer.repo.PeliculaRepository;
import com.cinetrailer.trailer.service.FileSystemStorageService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.web.PageableDefault;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/admin")
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private PeliculaRepository peliculaRepository;
    @Autowired
    private GeneroRepository generoRepository;
    @Autowired
    private FileSystemStorageService fileSystemStorageService;

    @GetMapping("")
    ModelAndView index(@PageableDefault(sort = "titulo", size = 5) Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Pelicula> peliculas = peliculaRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return new ModelAndView("admin/index").addObject("peliculas", peliculas);
    }

    @GetMapping("/peliculas/nuevo")
    ModelAndView nuevaPelicula() {
        List<Genero> generos = generoRepository.findAll(Sort.by("titulo"));

        return new ModelAndView("admin/nueva-pelicula").addObject("pelicula", new Pelicula()).addObject("generos", generos);
    }

    @PostMapping("/peliculas/nuevo")
    ModelAndView crearPelicula(@Validated Pelicula pelicula, BindingResult bindingResult) {

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors() || pelicula.getPortada().isEmpty()) {
            if (pelicula.getPortada().isEmpty()) {
                bindingResult.rejectValue("portada", "MultipartNotEmpty");
            }
            List<Genero> generos = generoRepository.findAll(Sort.by("titulo"));
            return new ModelAndView("admin/nueva-pelicula").addObject("pelicula", pelicula).addObject("generos", generos);
        }
        String rutaPortada = fileSystemStorageService.storage(pelicula.getPortada());
        pelicula.setRutaPortada(rutaPortada);

        peliculaRepository.save(pelicula);

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");
//        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin");
    }

    @GetMapping("/peliculas/{id}/editar")
    ModelAndView editarPelicula(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Optional<Pelicula> optionalPelicula = peliculaRepository.findById(id);
        if (optionalPelicula.isPresent()) {
            Pelicula pelicula = optionalPelicula.get();
            List<Genero> generos = generoRepository.findAll(Sort.by("titulo"));
//        Pelicula pelicula = peliculaRepository.getOne(id);
//        List<Genero> generos = generoRepository.findAll(Sort.by("titulo"));

            return new ModelAndView("admin/editar-pelicula")
                    .addObject("pelicula", pelicula).addObject("generos", generos);
        }
        else {
            return new ModelAndView("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: WHERE do you see gibberish?  Which button triggered that?

Comment: Why upload an image in the DB? It's a bad practice.

Comment: @azer-p why do you say that?

Comment: @tgdavies correction, not a bad practice but there's a lot of disadvantages

Comment: @TimRoberts no a bottom, when i click over the image

Comment: @azer-p sorry I specified wrong, i upload a reference to the location of the file in the database.

Comment: So, are you saying that the `<img>` displays correctly, but when you click on it, the exact same URL does not display correctly?  Does your `rutaPortada` include the file's extension?